# Post not sending variable to next page

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to send a post variable to the next page after inserting values into my table, dreamweaver generated this code for me, i tried tweaking it to make it work but with no success. Here is the code

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO links (url, ytname, timeout, `unique`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['url'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ytname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['timeout'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['unique'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_linkdb, $linkdb);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $linkdb) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "index.php?url=" . $_POST['unique'];

  header(sprintf($insertGoTo));
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: `header(sprintf($insertGoTo));` and where does `Location:` come in?

Comment: lol..... whoops. Thank you! fixed it

Comment: and I've been vampirized............. again. *sigh* you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Change your header function value.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO links (url, ytname, timeout, `unique`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['url'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ytname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['timeout'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['unique'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_linkdb, $linkdb);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $linkdb) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "index.php?url=" . $_POST['unique'];

  header("Location: /".sprintf($insertGoTo));

}
```